# Button is not centred even with resolution independent alignment

Tags: html, css

I have a button on my website, and I used resolution independent alignment. I checked two different computer screens with different resolutions and it looks alright, however, once opened on a larger aspect ratio screen or a mobile/tablet device it re-positions. On a larger aspect ratio screen the buttons moves to the left, on the smaller devices, it floats towards the right. I'm not 100% certain what could of gone wrong. Below is my CSS and HTML code.

HTML:

```
<div class="Welcome">
    <h1>Welcome to Beauty Factory Bookings</h1>
    <a href="website_link"><button>Book Appointment</button></a>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
    body {
        background: url('http://i.imgur.com/4mKmYMb.jpg') no-repeat fixed center center;
        background-size: cover;
        font-family: Montserrat;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;

    .Welcome {
        margin-top: 13%;
    }

    .Welcome h1 {
        text-align: center;
        font-family: Montserrat;
        font-size: 50px;
        text-transform: uppercase;
    }

    .Welcome button {
        height: 60px;
        width: 340px;
        background: #ff656c;
        border: 1px solid #e15960;
        color: #fff;
        font-weight: bold;
        text-transform: uppercase;
        font-size: 17px;
        font-family: Montserrat;
        outline: none;
        cursor: pointer;
        text-align: center;
        margin-left: 33%;
        margin-top: 3%;
        border-radius: 5px;
    }
```

Any idea how to fix this?

Comment: You really need to create a [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Basically this means that until you can't make the button here behave like the one on your website we won't be able to help you.

Comment: just do what i did using flex box.

Comment: I tried, it still does not work. Your solution might be perfectly fine, I think there is also something wrong with the rest of my code.

Comment: @Filip is there anyway i could see your website i could just check your src file that way.. or else just try uploading it to codepen, or GIThub

Comment: Yes. http://itecdigital.org.uk/2015/430926/BeautyFactoryBooking/Log_In.html

Comment: Use the following login details -->
user: admin
pass: admin

Comment: Check out my edit.. and you will it work. xD

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You center a html element, which has the **standard position** and is a **block element** with `margin-left: auto` and `margin-right: auto`.

It is a convention to write the first letter of classes and ids in lowercase.

[Example](https://jsfiddle.net/1a34e0cp/)

Answer (score 0):

create a new CSS property for `a` tag and set display to flex(takes up 100% of width; and justify content to center.

**EDIT**

After checking out your site, 
there is a margin-left of 15px coming from somewhere. Get rid of it if that is a possibility or else just add `margin-left: 0` to the `.Welcome a {...}`

```
.Welcome a {
  display: flex;
  /*set display mode of anchor to flex*/
  justify-content: center; /* Justify content center*/
  margin-left: 0; /* Add !important in case it is overwritten*/
}
```

---

```css
.Welcome {
  margin-top: 13%;
}
.Welcome h1 {
  text-align: center;
  font-family: Montserrat;
  font-size: 50px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}
.Welcome a {
  display: flex;
  /*set display mode of anchor to flex*/
  justify-content: center; /* Justify content center*/
}
.Welcome button {
  height: 60px;
  width: 340px;
  background: #ff656c;
  border: 1px solid #e15960;
  color: #fff;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-size: 17px;
  font-family: Montserrat;
  outline: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  text-align: center;
  border-radius: 5px;
}
```

```html
  <div class="Welcome">
    <h1>Welcome to Beauty Factory Bookings</h1>

      <a href="website_link">
        <button>Book Appointment</button>
      </a>

  </div>
```

Comment: Display flex on a page container? What happens with the rest of the elements in his page?

Comment: Honestly I use flex in everything since I have control of lot of things with it). I barely use `margin: 0 auto` to centralize stuff. Everyone has their own preferences.

Comment: I never use `0 auto` either since I don't like having to set `text-align: initial` on children. I use either flex or the `trasnform` where I can't use `flex`.

Comment: yeah.. flex made css styling so much easier and fun haha

Answer (score 0):

Just another way to do it:

I wrap your button in `div` and center the button using `text-align:center`
Don't forget to take out `margin-left: 33%;` in your css

**HTML**

```
<div class="Welcome">
    <h1>Welcome to Beauty Factory Bookings</h1>
    <div class="center">
        <a href="website_link"><button>Book Appointment</button></a>
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
 .Welcome {
   margin-top: 13%;
 }

 .Welcome h1 {
   text-align: center;
   font-family: Montserrat;
   font-size: 50px;
   text-transform: uppercase;
 }

 .center {
   text-align: center;
 }

 .Welcome button {
   height: 60px;
   width: 340px;
   background: #ff656c;
   border: 1px solid #e15960;
   color: #fff;
   font-weight: bold;
   text-transform: uppercase;
   font-size: 17px;
   font-family: Montserrat;
   outline: none;
   cursor: pointer;
   text-align: center;
   margin-top: 3%;
   border-radius: 5px;
 }
```

Example: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/EPyjXm